# How can i use a string i passed from a C# code to a C++ code (dll) with an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to pass a string from my c# program to a c++ DLL I created.
Whenever I try to use the string my program throws a System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt'

I have been able to pass other variable types like int and double from my C# code to my C++ code and use them, but passing string keeps throwing AccessViolationException.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Class Program{
  [DllImport("myDll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool test(string data);
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   test("Hello world");
  }
```

```
  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void test(string *data)
  {
  // I get an error whenever I asing *data to s;
  string s = *data;
  }
```

I expect the value in data to be assigned to s (in my c++ code) without throwing System.AccessViolationException error at run time

Comment: You can't use C++ types (such as std::string) when p/invoking. At least not easily and without pain. Refrain from using C++ data types as arguments for DLL-exported functions you want to call from C#. The marshaller will not translate your C# string into a pointer pointing to a native std::string object. Instead, depending on the setup of the P/Invoke method declaration for your native method, it will convert the C# string to    either a `wchar_t*` or `char*` pointer.  (note that using `char*` is privy to the subtleties and pitfalls of whatever text encoding your program is using)

Comment: @elgonzo I've tried getting the string value using its pointer as *char but it didn't work out. Please, can you help me with a guide or project on how to go about it?